# What is CRSH in Flywrench?

Tags: flywrench

On the level select screen for Flywrench, there is a statistic called CRSH which keeps increasing the more I play.

What is CRSH? Why does it keep increasing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been a while since I played this but I am pretty sure CRSH stands for crash, it counts how often you crashed (died) so far.

Comment: Well that explains why it keeps increasing...